# Issue with Root finding function

Tags: python, scipy

I am try to find the roots of a polynomial function using the code below. The polynomial is set-up as required, but my problem is that `scipy.optimize.newton(f, yields_0)` returns only a single value, when I was expecting it to return a list. I don't know how to solve this issue. I know that this isn't the best way of setting up the function `f` but I don't know how else to `rhs - bond.price` for each `bond` in the list `bonds`. Can `scipy.optimize.newton()` only deal with a function that returns a single value? And if so, how can I rewrite the code below?

```
    yields_list = []
    rhs_list = []
    def f(yields):
        for bond in bonds:
            rhs = 0
            bond_cashflow_series = bond.to_cash_flows().amounts
            vals_fromseries = bond_cashflow_series.values
            for i in range(0, len(vals_fromseries), 1):
                rhs = rhs + vals_fromseries[i]/(1+yields)**(i+1)


        return rhs_list.append(rhs - bond.price)


    yields_0 = 0.2
    list_required = scipy.optimize.newton(f, yields_0)
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to do.  Are you trying to find the yield rate of a bunch of different bonds simultaneously?  This code won't work for this, since they'll all have different yield rates.  The docs say that scipy.optimize.newton only works for a function of one variable.  Also, since you are trying to solve a polynomial, it would be worthwhile to include the optional fprime and fprime2 parameters.  If you can give some more details of what you're doing, I'm sure I can help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not clear to me exactly what your code is doing, but I can give you an example of a quick way to compute a bond yield.  Suppose flows is a list of cash flows at times 0, 1, 2, etc.  `flows[0]` is the negative of the price, `flows[1]` is the first coupon, ..., flows[-1] is the final coupon + the redemption value.

```
from numpy.polynomial.polynomial import Polynomial
# pv is present value as function of the discount rate
pv = Polynomial(flows)
f1 = pv.deriv(1)
f2 = pv.deriv(2)
v0 = 1/(1+yield_0)
v =  scipy.optimize.newton(pv, v0, fprime=f1, fprime2=f2)
yield = 1.0/v -1
```

This assumes that the first coupon is paid six months from the time at which the bond is purchased, as seems to be the case in your code.  The yield is per six-month period, and you'll have to adjust it to an annual yield.  If you want a more general method, where the first coupon can be paid at any period from the purchase date, you won't be able to use Polynomial.

I haven't tested this code; there may be errors in it.